# Scalable imtermediate data storage system with php daemon and nonblocking fopen

Tags: php, mysql, scalability, daemon

I am building a scalable data storage system.  n number of servers can have 100's of simultaneous data insertion requests to a mysql database.  I will be writing the data storage on each web server locally.  I need to be able to write the local storage of each web server to the mysql database when a threshold has been met(trigger).

I have a concept that has a PHP library using a non-blocking method of appending submitted data to a txt file.  A daemon runs on each web server.  This txt file accumulates rows of data (csv format) until the threshold is met and then the daemon zips the file and sends it to a collecting server that will unzip the data and insert it into the database.

My method for writing to the txt file is something like:

```
$fp = fopen($file, 'a+');
stream_set_blocking($fp, 0);

while($count < $loop) {
    if (flock($fp, LOCK_EX)) {
        fwrite($fp, $text);
    }
    flock($fp, LOCK_UN);
}

fclose($fp)
```

Lets just say I write a daemon on the server that moves the txt file to the collecting server every 2 minutes.  I am not sure about the exact process of moving the file and starting to write to a new (clean) file with concurrent connections.

I was thinking something like the daemon locks the file and copys it then erases all the data from the original and then unlocks it???  The copied file would be sent to the collector via the daemon.  I'm not sure how this will behave simultaneously if the above stream file write is running.

Is there a more efficient/faster/reliable solution collecting the data locally and then moving it to the collector?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

What you have seems like a perfectly reasonable model to me, so my answer is an optimization for it. It seems like you could fix the issue with using more than one spooling file. I'm imagining something like:

Write a file for two minutes (or until you reach your threshold or whatever your criteria is). Once you move on to the next file, copy and delete the old file. You could repeat this process indefinitely, including the timestamp in the file name to make sure you never have collisions.